# Accessing AVFrame using AVOption

Tags: ffmpeg, libav, libavcodec

`avcodec_get_frame_class()` is now deprecated but `AVFrame`'s docs still link to it to access `AVFrame`'s field using `AVOption`s. Is there an alternative way to get `AVFrame`'s `AVClass`? Should I just access the fields directly and forget about `AVOption`s?

I want my application to remain as stable as possible even on version changes so `AVOption`s looked like the better way to interface with FFmpeg.